# Shiny with HTML UI limited by Javascript OnLoad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, shiny

I am using `R` 3.0.1 with `Shiny` 0.7.0 to create a Shiny webpage with `HTML UI`.

It seems I have stumbled upon what seems to be either a limitation or a bug in Shiny regarding the `OnLoad()` event of the `body` element.

Since Shiny is not prepared for multiple HTML pages, as stated by Joe Cheng [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/GAiZ4m13EHY) I am trying to use `jQuery` instead to show and hide `divs` where necessary.

This works reasonably well except **if I hide divs in the OnLoad** event. In that case it seems `reactive input components` are no longer detected by `Shiny`.

Following you can see a test case for this:

**Server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$caption <- renderText({input$myInput})

})
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/library.js"></script>    
</head>

 <body onload="initForm();"> 


    <div id="dMenu">

        <a href="#" onclick="showFoo();">Show foo div</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#" onclick="showBar();">Show bar div</a>
    </div>

    <!-- some random div -->
    <div id="foodiv">This is the Foo div</div>

    <!-- div with reactive input -->                
    <div id="bardiv">
        This is the Bar div
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="myInput" class ="shiny-bound-input" name="myInput" autocomplete="off"> 
        <div id="caption" class="shiny-text-output shiny-bound-output"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**library.js**

```
function showFoo(){
    $('#foodiv').show();    
    $('#bardiv').hide(); 
}


function showBar(){
    $('#foodiv').hide();
    $('#bardiv').show();    
}


function initForm(){
    /*showFoo();    */
}
```

If you use this code as is Shiny will react to changes in the `myInput` component and write them to the `caption` component. If, on the other hand, you comment out the code in `initForm()` it will stop to react to whatever you write into `myInput`.

I tested this with Firefox 23.0.1.

Does anybody know if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this [shiny mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/hidden/shiny-discuss/Zd7HWzOaB7E/cqRF9M3h9p0J) post by Winston.

You can write

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$caption <- renderText({input$myInput})
  outputOptions(output, 'caption', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
})
```

to ensure that the element is still updated when hidden.

Comment: +1, that solved the problem, although I am still asking myself why this happens only if the `OnLoad` event is called. If I do not call it and simply hide and show again the element `Shiny` still reacts to nput.

Comment: I agree. I hope you don't mind, but I copied this issue to the shiny mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/N68EFR_uh_c .

Comment: that is completely ok. I will check your post in the Shiny mailing list from time to time to see if they have answered. :-)

Comment: FWIW, on the google forums, @YihueXie suggested another way of solving this problem by triggering the `hidden` and `shown` events after hiding or showing the `div` element.