# Action button does not work when hide container. shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have been working with shiny and I think that is so good, but I have a problem when use action button function, the problem is if hidden the container where I going to put information of response, the action button does not work.

For example.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Example Tabs</title>
 <script src ="shared/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src ="shared/shiny.js"></script>
 <script src ="actionbutton.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form class="span12 menu-med-upload">
  <div class="row-fluid">
   <button id="uploadFasta" type="button" class="btn action-button shiny-bound-input" >go!</button>
   <button id="show">Show</button>
   <button id="hide">Hide</button>
  </div>
 </form>
 <div id="table" class="shiny-html-output">asdasd</div>
 <script>
  $("#table").hide();
  $("#show").on("click",function(){
   $("#table").show();
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 output$table <- renderText({
  if(input$uploadFasta == 0)
   return(NULL)
  return("Clicked!")
 })
})
```

if I comment the line  $("#table").hide(); it works with out problem, but if hidden the container does not work.

Thanks for all.

Comment: What `$("#table").hide()` is supposed to do in the app ?  Can't you do the same with ordinary (only R) programming ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stéphane, this line is other language ( javascript ), and with it you hide a container identified with the id = table and you can not do it with only R, because R is used in server part and javascript is used in client part.

Comment: I don't know what the app is supposed to do but why can't you use `conditionalPanel()` for instance ?

Comment: I don't understand what is a conditionalPanel() but a think that the problem is with a request of server, because the server doesn't do anything after hide and show the content. may be, somebody know how is make the shiny tabsets? because the core of tabset function is like the problem that I have. thanks :D

Comment: Acutally I don't understand why don't you use the **ui.R** file (used to make the interface in R code, whereas you directly use html).

Comment: sure, this is other way to create apps with shiny, why use it ? is simple, when you use html file directly you can modified all structure of your app, like this http://spark.rstudio.com/raburgoso/sipgo, but it's a little more dificult. if you want to learn more http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#html-ui :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled on a very similar problem not long ago, although it affected an `input` element. See [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166322/shiny-with-html-ui-limited-by-javascript-onload) for more information, as well as the linked [Google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/N68EFR_uh_c).

Basically, the problem was that Shiny loses track of a `reactive` element if it is hidden when loading the `DOM` (not sure if this is what happens in your case).

Anyway, you might want to try 2 possible solutions.

- First one is to trigger the `shown` event when showing the `table` div. This solution is more fine-grained as it allows you to control at every moment whether to react or not to any hidden element. To do this just change your `Javascript` to do following:

  ```
  $("#table").show().trigger('shown');
  ```
- The other possibility is to instruct Shiny not to ignore the `table` div when it is hidden. This solution will make any affected element react always. To achieve this change your `server.R` file to include this line:

  ```
  outputOptions(output, 'table', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  ```

Comment: thanks for the answer Guillem, I'm going to try it, and I think that the best form to do it is with Javascript, is more formal.