# values not updating after hiding/showing sections

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to create a flexdashboard with shiny that renders a section containing a valueBox. However, this section should only be visible when the displayed value is not 0. Otherwise the boxes should be shown and populated with the selected value.

[image]

[Building on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77551707/hide-section-on-condition) the first part works by using js code (see below) and the section disappears when the value is 0

[image]

but the value does not change back when the input changes

[image]

I found this [possibly related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166322/shiny-with-html-ui-limited-by-javascript-onload/19177028?) but am unable to adapt it to my use-case.

So here is my code starting with the the YAML of the `.rmd` file

```
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
runtime: shiny
---
```

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)

numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 0, min = 0, max = 1)
```

#### Valuebox {.value-box #box}

```
renderValueBox({
  valueBox(input$obs)
})
```

and the js code that search all sections containing "box" and hides them when its value-ouput is 0

```
$(document).on("shiny:inputchanged", function (event) {
    // Find all sections with IDs containing "box"
    var sections = $('[id*="box"]');
    
    // Check if the input with id "obs" has changed
    if (event.name === 'obs') {
        // Show all sections
        sections.show();
        return;
    }

    // Loop through each section
    sections.each(function() {
        var section = $(this);
      
        var valueOutput = section.find('.value-output');

        // Check if the value is 0 and hide or show the section accordingly
        if (valueOutput.length > 0) {
            if (parseFloat(valueOutput.text()) === 0) {
                section.hide();
            } else {
                section.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-force-reactive-graphs-to-plot-evaluate-when-not-in-focus-in-flexdashboard-tabs/128924) forum post the output must resume while hidden. This can be done by setting `suspendWhenHidden` to `FALSE`.

```
outputOptions(output, "id", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

I found it tricky to pinpoint the exact `id` of the output in question when using flexdashboard. It appears to be some random id that is created on start-up of the app, e.g. `out2132b...`. Since there is an order to the outputs one can address them by position

```
outputs <- names(outputOptions(output))
outputOptions(output, outputs[2], suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

Or iterate over all of them. Now, the values should be updated even when the section in question is hidden.